# TemplateDoesNotExist Exception - Django is not loading template from namespaced template

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.2.10

I have an app called myapp, and this is my folder structure:

```
/path/to/project
    ...
    myapp
        ...
        templates
            myapp
                index.html
```

When I place `index.html` in `/path/to/project/myapp/templates/index.html` I am able to view the template, however, when I place `index.html` in the correct subfolder (as shown above) and [recommended in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/) (as a way of "namespacing"the templates per application).

I get the eror TemplateNotFound.

This is the relevant portion of my settings.py

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
                 ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',                
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Why is Django not able to find the template, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, that in 'settings.py' your app name ('myapp') is in 'INSTALLED_APPS' and make sure you are calling template by 'myapp/index.html' in your 'views.py'.